# Firebase Error: "Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap"

Tags: java, android, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap

I had a structure in my database that worked perfectly, but then I add the following node to my database and since then I'm getting this error. If I delete the "commentList" node it works again. Why would it change from a list to a Hashmap?

[My db structure. It worked before adding that "commentList"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UibAG.png)

The code responsible for this:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlidC.png)

Here the log error:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a List while deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToParameterizedType(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:233)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:176)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$100(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:580)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:550)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:420)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:214)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:178)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.access$100(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:47)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:580)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:550)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:420)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:214)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:178)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToParameterizedType(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:247)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:176)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:101)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:239)
    at com.example.xandi.whib.MainActivity$3.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:236)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

What is causing this and how would I fix this?

Comment: Please don't post images of code.  It's far better to copy the text of the code into the question, and format it with a code block, so it's easier to read and search.  Everything we need to understand the problem should be directly in the question itself, not linked somewhere else.

Comment: can you please post code. So we can dry debug the code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Code sample would definitely help here.

Comment: You have a problem in your Server class

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late, but I'll post it for others who encounter the same issue. Firebase real-time database does not store collections in lists but **HashMap**s. Your model property should be more like this:

```
var commentList: HashMap<String, String>? = null
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be sure that the firebase object is array, not map, like that: 
[firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiX2O.png)

I've had the same problem, the solution was check the type of object, directly in firebase database and change Map(HashMap) to Array(List)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try to explain your answer.

Comment: So improve your answer: edit it and add your comment